# Efficient way to structure database raffle site

Tags: php, mysql

I'm planning to make some kind of a raffle site as part of some gaming site. Now I was brainstorming about the best way to structure the database where the different raffles are stored. So my idea is to create a row for each raffle and give each ticketnumber its own column (which will hold the userid of the owner of the ticket). But as a raffle can get up to 1500 tickets I doubt if this is the best way to structure the table. Does anyone has another (better) suggestion how to do this or is this the best way?

Comment: 1500 is a trivial number of rows for any db

Comment: 1500 would be the number of the tickets (=column) 1-1500 for each row (=raffle). Is 1500 also trivial for # of colums?

Comment: yes, and thats a small number as far as any db is concerned

Comment: 1500 colums nooooo. rows > user_id | ticket_id =1500 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest having two tables. One called **raffle** which holds the raffle information for the current raffle and one called **raffle_ticket** holding the ticket information for the raffles. Here is the following structure I propose:

**raffle** columns:

- raffle_id (Auto increment primary key)
- raffle_name (Raffle name)
- raffle_date (date of raffle)
- .... Other raffle information

**raffle_ticket** columns:

- raffle_ticket_id (Auto increment primary key)
- raffle_id (Foreign key linking to the raffle_id in the raffle table)
- raffle_user_id (Foreign key linking to the user_id in your user table)
- raffle_num (The number of the ticket in the current raffle (Can be generated with `SELECT MAX(raffle_num)+1 as newrafflenumber FROM raffle_ticket WHERE raffle_id = CURRENT_RAFFLE_ID;` if you want sequential numbers per raffle)

You may need something slightly different, but that's what I would suggest.

Comment: That's where I was looking for! Thanks!